# firebaseadmin sdk throws priorty exception during initialization

Tags: asp.net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Followed official doc and set the code below but it throws exception after configure services in runtime with message:

> Exception caught: 'System.ArgumentException' in FirebaseAdmin.dll ("Invalid priority value: 0. Only 'high' and 'normal' are allowed.")

```
       // Initialize the Firebase Admin SDK
    var checkPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
    FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
    {
        Credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault(),
    });
```

config file path is correct..
Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Do you have any JSON deserialization code? That's an error thrown by the `FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.AndroidConfig` class when attempting to deserialize an invalid priority value.

Comment: No I have added only these lines to project